# Bluetooth mouse latency on linux

Tags: debian, mouse, bluetooth, latency

I bought a logitech MX anywhere 2S, and I'm using it on Debian 9.

when I started using it got a hight latency.

I resolved the problem using the following command:

> su
>
> echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_latency &&
> echo 6 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_min_interval &&
> echo 7 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_max_interval

then I need to disconnect and reconnect the device in blueman-manager.

Every time i put my computer to sleep and wake it I need to repeat all this steps!!!

Anyone knows how do i fix it permanently?

tks!